# How can an evil spirit take control of a human body during REM sleep?

Tags: biology, genetics, sleep, demons

I have a friend who is a really nice guy. The problem is that he was born as a half demon. While he looks completely normal, he possesses a spirit inside him called "Amon". This being forces him to experience certain demonic urges, which he must constantly suppress while awake.

When my friend falls asleep, he loses control of his body to Amon. The demon must wait for him to fall into his REM cycle, which is the deepest mode of sleep in which the human begins to dream and will not be easily awakened. During this time, my friend becomes possessed and gains his demonic abilities, such as super strength, speed, durability, and power of flight. The demon then goes out to do horrible things and commit murder and mayhem. When cornered by this creature one night, I asked this creature what it's name was, and it's response was that "**I AM**.....**DEVILMAN**".

[REM sleep is supposed to be the cycle in which your muscles are paralyzed](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2012/07/120711131030.htm), which prevents your body from moving. This is intentional as to stop you from acting out your dreams, and should prevent an evil spirit from taking you over. How is it that Amon is able to bypass this human drawback created by millions of years of evolution?

Comment: Many children need a waterproof sheet on their bed....

Comment: No self-respecting demon could accept being called by any name but his own.... ;-)  Besides, I'd be much more impressed by the response, "Amon... now you will kneel...."

Comment: imagine your friend is blind... so would DEVILMAN suddenly gain sight? but I read that blind person can hallucinate smell and sound just no color during REM.

Comment: @user6760, that's a fascinating question.  If the blindness were due to a cognitive processing problem, the answer would be easily yes.  Cool idea.  Cheers!

Comment: Answer: magic. Does this even need an explanation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The demon must wait for him to fall into his REM cycle, which is the
>   deepest mode of sleep

EDIT - A minor frame-challenge here. REM is not only characterised by sleep-paralysis, it also is when we dream. If a person is essentially good then they will be the same way in their dreams and unlikely to go on a rampage of evil even if the demon could manipulate the dreams.

> How is it that Amon is able to bypass this human drawback [of paralysis]

A simple way to bypass this problem is to avoid REM and go for N3 sleep, the deepest stage of non-rapid eye movement (NREM) sleep. At this point his victim will be most like a zombie and yet still able to perambulate. Note that your friend will have no memories of the evil activities on waking.

An ex-girlfriend of mine would sometimes walk around and talk nonsense during this stage of sleep. She was impossible to wake and never had any recollections of it the next day!

**Answer**

Amon spent a long time searching for a victim who was a **sleepwalker**. Unfortunately for your friend, he fit the bill.

> Why some people sleepwalk is not fully understood, but researchers
>   have discovered a few risk factors. For example, sleepwalking tends to
>   run in families, which indicates a genetic link.
>
> According to researchers at Stanford, people with certain psychiatric
>   issues, such as obsessive-compulsive disorder and depression, have an
>   increased risk of sleepwalking. Also, people who are prone to the
>   disorder may be more likely to sleepwalk when they are sleep deprived,
>   anxious or have an illness.
>   https://www.sleepassociation.org/sleep-disorders/more-sleep-disorders/sleep-walking/

Comment: Sleepwalking seems to occur mostly during non-REM sleep, according to the following sources: https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/000808.htm, https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/conditions/sleepwalking

Comment: @sumelic - absolutely true and I was aware of that. My answer contained an implicit frame-challenge. I'll make it more obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

How can a demon take control of a human body during REM sleep? All they have to do is...

### Follow the solution procurement process

If, in the course of performing their assigned tasks, Amon the Damon determines that it makes business sense to take control of your friend’s body during rapid eye movement (REM) sleep, they needs to follow the regular solution procurement process as outlined in the relevant HellCo corporate standards and implemented by the Hellish Procurement tools on the infernal intranet, accessible by individual-contributor demons.

Not having yet consulted with HellCo, all can do is make an informed guess of the big outlines of such an underworld process. Specific details may vary, but the gist of the process is almost certainly conformant to the uniform Heaven and Hell best practices.

1. Amon first needs to raise their request with their immediate line manager, during one of their regular one-on-one meetings. They should go into the meeting prepared with a short PowerPoint presentation describing (a) the specific tasks which require them to take over your friend during REM sleep, (b) the potential business impact, estimated, of being unable to complete those tasks in time, (c) the estimated cost of the solution, expressed in Standard International Damned Souls (SIDS) equivalent.
2. After obtaining the buy-in from their immediate manager, and securing an approval e-mail, Amon needs to log in to the infernal intranet using the corporate Venial Private Network (VPN), and go to the Hellish Procurement portal. In the portal they must initiate a new requisition, and select a catalog item, under Solutions › Possession › Unwilling › Asleep; the tool will provide a cost calculation, based on the automatic selection of the lowest available price, and an estimation of delivery.
3. When making the requisition, Amon must not forget to attach the e-mail from their immediate manager giving explicit approval; they must fill-in the reference ID of the project; and in the comments field they must insert a short description of the business requirements.
4. Note that some solutions available in Hellish Procurement provide a functional demonstration; if such functionality is available, the corporate procurement standards require that Amon avail themself of the possibility to test the solution for compatibility and suitability. For example, several possession solutions for unwilling and asleep subjects have a try-before-you-buy version capable of providing limited control over the subject, usually involving either inducing a partial erotic dream (SFW imagery only, no finishing) or tossing the cover sheets. Amon is responsible to download and install the trial version; they must mention in the comments field that the trial was successful.
5. In all cases the final responsibility for the business adequacy of the requisitioned solution lies with the requestor. Amon must demonstrably perform due diligence in order to make sure that the expenditure will allow completing the assigned tasks. Failure to perform due diligence to the satisfaction of the Procurement Oversight department risks disciplinary action, up to and including termination from HellCo, involuntary separation and assignment to Heaven in the role of a singing angel.
6. Solutions are always delivered electronically over the infernal intranet. Physical delivery is not allowed. In order to successfully download the solution, Amon must use the download link within three business days from the time of the dispatch of the e-mail containing the link. Be aware that solution approval and download e-mails are sent from Central Hell time zone. In most cases, an external USB stick is required, not provided by HellCo. Amon must use their own stick, or a stick procured and expended by the project.
7. Once the solution has been downloaded, Amon must install it as a plugin in their unwilling subject possession working environment; the solution will then provide the functionality of taking over the body of the unwilling subject while in REM sleep.

   If Amon does not feel confortable installing the solution they must raise a ticket with the Infernal Technologies (IT) Support, by clicking on the IT Support icon and filling in a request form. Installation services are provided free of charge from the corporate worst-shore incompetency center in Tartarus.

   The number of possession instances, and the duration of the possession, depend on the available license. Using the procured solution for any purpose other than performing the assigned tasks in the specific project is forbidden; HellCo has strict agreements with the solution providers, and breaching these agreements risks disciplinary action, up to and including termination from HellCo, involuntary separation and assignment to Heaven in the role of a singing angel.

Comment: Fascinating! You've made Hell almost as soul-rendingly dull as a "real" job!

Answer (score 1):

**How can a demon take control of a human body during REM sleep?**

I don't know about daemons, but REM sleep is the perfect time for this to happen.

REM sleep is very similar to what happens during hypnosis.  The conscious mind (inner monologue) is turned off, and one's perception of current reality is controlled by the hypnotist's voice or by the brain's dream generation mechanism.

[Wikipedia: Hypnosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypnosis#Historical_definitions) says:

> Joe Griffin and Ivan Tyrrell (the originators of the human givens
>   approach) define hypnosis as "any artificial way of accessing the REM
>   state, the same brain state in which dreaming occurs" and suggest that
>   this definition, when properly understood, resolves "many of the
>   mysteries and controversies surrounding hypnosis". They see the
>   REM state as being vitally important for life itself, for programming
>   in our instinctive knowledge initially (after Dement and
>   Jouvet) and then for adding to this throughout life. They explain
>   this by pointing out that, in a sense, all learning is post-hypnotic,
>   which explains why the number of ways people can be put into a
>   hypnotic state are so varied: anything that focuses a person's
>   attention, inward or outward, puts them into a trance.

In the case of hypnosis, the automatic paralysis doesn't happen.
When your daemon takes over, all it needs to do is to disable the paralysis and insert its own input in place of the dream generation.
That's exactly what a hypnotist does.

You might find some helpful ideas in [What Is Hypnosis](https://www.why-we-dream.com/hypnosis.htm):

> All the many methods for inducing hypnosis are paralleled by aspects of how the REM state is normally induced and maintained. Shock inductions, when hypnosis is instantaneously induced through an unexpected occurrence, such as the hypnotist suddenly thumping a table or ringing a bell, fires the orientation response into action, just as happens at the start of REM sleep. And inducing deep relaxation creates the same electrical patterns in the brain as occurs in REM sleep.